# Action Bar on Android is still showing despite using NoActionBar theme

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-12, google-pixel

I am using the theme `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar` ([docs](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#material3-themes)) for my Android app.

I am also calling `getActionBar().hide()` in the MainActivity.

On nearly all my devices, the Action Bar is not displaying. However on one device, a Pixel 6 running Android 12, I still see the Action Bar. I am sure I've installed the latest version of my app.

Any ideas why the Action Bar is still hanging around on this one device?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem (I thought) until I realized that I had set the .NoActionBar style in my values/themes.xml but NOT in my values-night/themes.xml and the device with the "issue" was in dark mode.

Solution:
Set Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar in both values/themes.xml and values-night/themes.xml.

Comment: this was my case !